# mongodb E11000 keyValue is random string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When using a collation
the MongoDB duplicate key error E110000
returns a random string for the keyValue
e.g.
"name": "Foo to the Bar"
returns as
"name": "3EEOEO71+)K"

When not using a collation it is returned correctly
e.g.
"name": "Foo to the Bar"
returns as
"name": "Foo to the Bar"

Why is this happening?
How can I both use a collation AND have the correct value returned?

Comment: What collation did you use?  Is that "random string" truly random, or is it the same for a specific value?  This could be an encoding difference.

Comment: No it is not truly random. I get the same string returned for the same request to that document. Each document returns a different string, but that string is consistently returned. I'm guessing it's the encrypted value. It is happening when trying to create a duplicate value on a unique entry, on post and patch.

Comment: Collation is - locale: 'en', strength: 1, Numeric Ordering: true, Alternate: shifted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue with `{ locale: 'en', strength: 1 }`.

I believe mongo uses a hash/mapping function (when using a locale) in order to compute (in)equality.

The "weird" value you see may be the computer binary value, blindly translated to readable characters.

Unfortunately I don't think the error contains the original values.

Therefore the only solution would be to simply display e.g. `A user already exist with the same nickname` without mentioning the value, or pick up the original values from the object you've just submitted.